# How to select departments having all books published by a single publisher in the given relational schema?

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

```
create table STUDENT
(
    regno varchar(5) primary key,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    major varchar(20) not null,
    bdate date not null
);

create table COURSE
(
    courseno int primary key,
    cname varchar(20) not null,
    dept varchar(20) not null
);


create table TEXT
(   
    book_isbn int primary key,
    booktitle varchar(20) not null,
    publisher varchar(20) not null
);


create table ENROLL
(
    regno varchar(20) not null,
    courseno int not null,
    sem int not null,
    book_isbn int not null,
    foreign key (regno) references STUDENT,
    foreign key (courseno) references COURSE,
    foreign key (book_isbn) references TEXT
);

create table BOOK_ADOPTION
(
    courseno int not null,
    sem int not null,
    book_isbn int not null,
    foreign key (courseno) references COURSE,
    foreign key (book_isbn) references TEXT
)
```

;

This is the provided schema for student database. I have to find all those departments which get all their books published by the same publisher. How do I do this using SQL?

I have joined the tables using

```
select *
    from 
        (select *
         from course as c , book_adoption as b , text as t
         where c. courseno = b. courseno and t. book_isbn = b. book_isbn)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ1Rq.png)

Now I am not able to form logic for how to compare the values for each dept 
Can group by  be used ? Is there a way to access tuples in a group?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried that doesn't work so we can help you get past where you're stuck?

Comment: Where is department table? from which table the department information is supposed to be retrieved?

Comment: @Chet it looks like dept is a string field in course.

Comment: If you haven't tried anything yet, you'll need to join book_adoption to text and course. Then group on dept from course and check whether the number of distinct publishers in text is 1. All you have to do is write the SQL to do that :)

Comment: @Forklift hmm.... Thank you.... Aditya should have provided that information..

Comment: What have you done so far?  We can't help if you don't post your solution.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have added what logic I have been trying to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Could be you  can check the distinct publisher in this relation

```
  select c.dept 
  from COURSE as c
  INNER JOIN BOOK_ADOPTION as ba on ba.courseno = c.courseno
  INNER JOIN TEXT as t on  ba.book_isbn = t.book_isbn
  GROUP BY c.dept
  HAVING COUNT( disctint t.publisher) = 1
```